# interface and implement's name, which is better?

Tags: java, interface

```
public interface MemcachedAccessor {

     void set(String key, Object value, int cacheTime, long timeout,
        TimeUnit timeUnit);

     Object get(String key);
}
```

I have one interface: `MemcachedAccessor` and an implementation: `MemcachedAccessorImpl`.

Which name style is better?

`MemcachedAccessor` and `MemcachedAccessorImpl`

or

`MemcachedAccess` and `MemcachedAccessImpl`

?

any rules?

Comment: I have edited your post assuming that MemcachedAccess(or) is the interface and MemcachedAccess(or)Impl the concrete implementation. Rollback if it is not what you meant.

Comment: If you only one implementation why keep the interface?

Comment: @mlk To allow easy mocking during testing--not all implementations need to be explicitly named. In this case being able to simulate a cache miss might be important. Your point is well-taken, however.

Comment: Most mocking frameworks support mocking classes.

Comment: If your implementation works in-memory as its name suggests, then I'd suggest there's no point in mocking it anyway - interface or no interface.

Comment: @mlk Yep, and it's easier not to. Like I said, I understand your point--I just believe that in most cases the cost of introducing an interface early is lower than the cost of introducing one later, although IDEs mitigate this to some degree. That doesn't mean I believe *everything* should have an interface (I don't), but I think pretty carefully before *not* having one.

Comment: @AlexHumphrey I guess he is making an abstraction for the [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) so it is probably not in-memory.

Comment: @maba - That makes the question is **so much clearer**. The fact that it's going to be used to access another system makes it an excellent candidate for an interface and mocking. Perhaps jiafu should mention that in the question if it's correct?

Comment: @AlexHumphrey Even if we're not discussing memcached, there absolutely *is* a reason to mock it--to simulate hits/misses without having to load the cache appropriately, check appropriate `set` values, etc--the point is that interfaces make it easier to deal with unanticipated implementation and testing needs, and I'd argue a cache is something that should be pretty flexible in both.

Comment: @DaveNewton my argument was that if a) the cache was implemented using something in memory (using a HashMap for example) and b) it was the only implementation, then you should easily be able to recreate most conditions in your tests without mocking. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexHumphrey Of course not--you could do the same thing with anything. It's not a question of capability, it's a question of ease.

Answer (score 7):

The interface could be even more general:

```
public interface CacheAccessor {
}
```

While the implementation shows the intent (to access a [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) distributed cache):

```
public class MemcachedAccessor implements CacheAccessor {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be contrarian, I'll say neither, and instead vote for:

`Memcacheable` and `DefaultMemcacheable` or:

`Memcached` and `DefaultMemcached`

There are no "rules" per se, but "-able"/"-ible" interface names are pretty common. The only *real* rule is to name things in a way that clearly and concisely indicates their intent. I extend that a bit to try and make sure that names (hence code) sound good when read out loud, like the code is telling a story.

Answer (score 2):

I'd only use names like accessor when issueing a command pattern or so. In this it's

```
class MemCache implements Cache {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an interface, you'll most certainly avoid *Impl, because it indicates Implementation of the interface.

**EDIT**
This answer was posted before the question was edited by another user, but ok, keep down-voting :)
In addition, my personal preference is to use .Net style for instantly visible clarity: interface would be `ICachedAccessor`, and the class implementing it would be `CachedAccessor`.

Comment: That style has fallen into disfavor in the Java world, for some time (probably around Effective Java-ish or a bit before). IMO it makes sense to drop it, too, for a variety of reasons. The most glaring are that (a) it's just ugly, and (b) people using it don't need to know it's an interface--just that it's a `CachedAccessor`. It also makes things ugly if whatever comes after the `I` is also an `I`. And so on. It highlights something that doesn't need to be highlighted, and arguably shouldn't be.

Comment: This is a matter of a personal preference, and I respect that. I like to know clearly what is what. Example: in ZK framework you have `org.zkoss.zul.api.Window` interface and `org.zkoss.zul.Window` implementation - the class has useful methods that are not exposed by the interface (talking about bad practice...) Bottom line, I want to look at the object declaration in the plain text editor and know whether it is an interface or not - I'm a developer and I like to have that information at hand.

Comment: @Less Wanting to know, without looking at anything else, by looking at a single line, *is* a personal preference--the general arguments against the `I` convention are fairly objective, and language-neutral. Classes *very* often have methods not exposed by the interface, this is not unusual at all. I suspect the vast majority of people asking, answering, and commenting on here are *also* developers, I'm not sure what was gained by highlighting that.

Comment: This is pointless discussion and I'll make my final word by saying: (a) I started Java after few years of `c# / .net / c++ / COM`, (b) not gonna change my mind, (c) whether something is ugly or beautiful is pretty much subjective thing, yet this is your first argument against `I`.

Comment: @Less It's one of *my* first arguments against `I`, but it's not among the set of *general* arguments, which are well-enumerated elsewhere. Debates are only pointless if you refuse to learn anything from it, like any other argument. I don't care if you change your mind or not.

Comment: @Less In c# I prefix interfaces with an `I`, in Java I don't. I try to stick with the conventions in each language. Then most people are happy. I guess that you use `methodName()` in Java and not `MethodName()`. That is also a convention.

Comment: @maba +1 'cause incidentally I do :)

Comment: Personally, I hate the "I" prefix.  It gives you no information you can't obtain by simply looking at the class header.  I think "public interface" is perfectly understandable.  It makes about as much sense to me as the prefixing of all member variables with "m" (for member) to indicate scope or "i","s" (int, string) to indicate type (some people even do both).